# how can i move multiple files where the file names and paths are in columns of a database table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

files locations are stored in database, and when i delete the table records/rows from the files table, i need to move the files to another directory (an archive directory).

there are 2 tables at play.  a jobs table and files table.  jobs have files.  when deleting a job i need to delete the job entry from jobs table, but also i need to delete file(s) entries from files table, but the actual files are not be be deleted... they are to be moved (archived).

here is the entire delete script that is attempting to delete records from 2 tables and move files to another folder.  the deleting of records from both tables works.  only one file is moved though.  if there are multiple files, it doesn't move all the files.  i tried wrapping the rename line with a while line.  i tried wrapping the entire if($dbrow) section in the same while clause.  i can't get this to work with while to loop through all the files.  maybe a foreach is in order?  how can i do that?

```
<?php
/* 
 delete-job.php
 Deletes job entry from the 'jobs' table and also deletes file entry/entries from 'files' table and moves (archives) files
*/

//check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {

//get id value
$id = $_GET['id'];

$dbresult = mysql_query("SELECT jobs.*, files.* FROM jobs INNER JOIN files WHERE files.jobid = jobs.id") or die(mysql_error());
$dbrow = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult);

    if($dbrow) {

        $name = $dbrow['name'];
        $path = $dbrow['path'];
        $count = $dbrow['count'];
        $approved = $dbrow['approved'];
        $approved_date = $dbrow['approved_date'];
        $jobid = $dbrow['jobid'];
        $timedateadded = $dbrow['timedateadded'];
        $currentdate = date("m-d-Y_H-i-s");
        $archivepath = "uploads/archive/".$name;

        rename("".$path."", "".$archivepath."");

        //delete the entry/entries
        //$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error()); //delete from just jobs table
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE jobs, files FROM jobs INNER JOIN files WHERE jobs.id = $id AND files.jobid = jobs.id") or die(mysql_error()); //also delete file records from files table that belong to the deleted jobs

        header("Location: view-jobs.php"); //redirect back to the view page

    } //end if($dbrow)

} //end if isset

else { //if id isn't set, or isn't valid...

    header("Location: view-jobs.php"); //redirect back to view page

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want or did you try that already? (Edited)

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $dbresult = mysql_query("SELECT jobs.*, files.* FROM jobs INNER JOIN files WHERE files.jobid = jobs.id") or die(mysql_error());

    while($dbrow = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult))
    {


        $name = $dbrow['name'];
        $path = $dbrow['path'];
        $count = $dbrow['count'];
        $approved = $dbrow['approved'];
        $approved_date = $dbrow['approved_date'];
        $jobid = $dbrow['jobid'];
        $timedateadded = $dbrow['timedateadded'];
        $currentdate = date("m-d-Y_H-i-s");
        $archivepath = "uploads/archive/".$name;

        rename("".$path."", "".$archivepath."");

        //delete the entry/entries
        //$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error()); //delete from just jobs table




    }

    $result = mysql_query("DELETE jobs, files FROM jobs INNER JOIN files WHERE jobs.id = $id AND files.jobid = jobs.id") or die(mysql_error()); //also delete file records from files table that belong to the deleted jobs

    header("Location: view-jobs.php"); //redirect back to the view page

}else { //if id isn't set, or isn't valid...

header("Location: view-jobs.php"); //redirect back to view page

}

?>
```